# Add class to the X items with DDRMenu Token template

Tags: templates, dotnetnuke, token, ddrmenu

I'm trying to create a menu with an image in the center using DDRMenu Menu Token template (see [link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/DDRMenu-token-templates)).
To do that, I have to create an empty space where the image will be by adding a margin to the item number X of my menu.

Let's say I have 6 items in my menu root, I have to add a class to the fourth item for the margin.

I'm having trouble to add that class.
Here is a basic template:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    [*>NODE-TOP]
    </ul>
</nav>
[>NODE-TOP]
    <li>
        <a href="[=URL]">
            [=TEXT]
        </a>
        [?NODE]
            <div>
                <ul>
                    [*>NODE]
                </ul>
            </div>
        [/?]
    </li>
[/>]
[>NODE]
    <li>
        <a href="[=URL]">
            [=TEXT]
        </a>
    </li>
[/>]
```

Is there a way to know the index of the item ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about index, you could hack a bit by using Keywords

```
class="[=KEYWORDS]"
```

If you really need the index, I think you should use xslt version with position()
see http://www.dnnhero.com/Premium/Tutorial/tabid/259/ArticleID/12/Beginning-XSLT-with-DDRMenu-for-DotNetNuke-Part-2.aspx

Comment: Using XSLT seems a better option since the keywords can be changed in the CMS.

Thx !